# Big O notation in calculus and discrete math

Tags: connections

Just to connect my knowledge, I want to know is the big O notation in algorithms similar to O(x) in Taylor Maclaurin of function in calculus?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Because they have the same definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it should be noted that the relevant limits are different. In calculus you are usually sending some distance to zero, while in algorithms you are usually sending the size of the problem to infinity. But O notation is compatible with both of these.